# How to merge Core Data Model from Package with main application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have a package that has its own Core Data Model which I can access from inside the package. However, I would like to access and modify that Core Data from inside of my main application.

Looking at the [following post](https://nemecek.be/blog/42/how-to-create-core-data-database-from-multiple-model-files) I would like to merge the two models into one, however, after multiple attempts it does not seem to work.

```
let bundle1 = Bundle(for: EntityFromPackage.self)
let bundle2 = Bundle(for: EntityFromApp.self)

let model = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [bundle1, bundle2])!
container = PersistentContainer(name: "Database", managedObjectModel: model)
```

I am getting the Database.sqlite file but it still only contains tables from the main application Core Data.

The way I am initializing my Package Core Data is:

```
let modelURL = Bundle.module.url(forResource:"Package", withExtension: "momd")
let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL!)
container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Package", managedObjectModel: model!)
```

Then I add *PackagePersistenceController.shared* application Initializer.

Yet if I try to FetchRequest the data inside application, I get:

> "The fetch request's entity xxx 'Entity' appears to be from a different NSManagedObjectModel than this context's"

Not sure what I am doing wrong with the first Code Block above that will not do the merge. Thanks.

Comment: This is not SwiftUI

Comment: If you try a NSFetchRequest instead, does it work?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I need FetchRequest to use inside of SwiftUI and track updates. The problem is that merge does not seem to work as Database only includes core data from application and not package.

Comment: I meant to try it to rule out any issue with the FetchRequest type.

Comment: If you set a `.environment(\.managedObjectContext, container)` on the parent view, then your environment scope should point to your custom/merged object model, and the `@FetchRequest` should have access to those models. I think? Let me know if this works and I'll move this to an answer. Happy coding!